# How can I populate list with ng-repeat with array cells value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, controller

I have an array where there is stored string that was splitted. I would like to now make a controller that would put each of this splitted strings into next li elements on the list. I know how to do ng-repeat with objects but i'm not sure how to do it with array cells?

```
var app = angular.module("pageApp", []);
app.controller('populateController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.dat=[];
    $http.get('/api').success(function(data) {
        $scope.dat= data[0];
    });
    var str = $scope.dat.guide;
    var res= str.split("~");
})

 new Manual({
        name: 'name1',
        category_name: 'sewing',
        difficulty_level: 'easy',
        guide: 'guide1' +'~2. guide2' +'~3. guide3' +'~4. guide4' +'~5. guide5'
    }),
```

Comment: Can you post your data structure or a small sample of your data as I'm not too sure what you mean by _array cells_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the way you're creating the array it will always be empty as a `$http` request is asynchronous also store the result of the `split()` as a variable on the `$scope`, so make your code like this.

```
$scope.dat=[];
$http.get('/api').success(function(data) {
    $scope.dat= data[0];
    var str = $scope.dat.guide;
    $scope.guides = str.split("~");
});
```

Now to display them in a list you can do this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.guides = ('guide1' + '~2. guide2' + '~3. guide3' + '~4. guide4' + '~5. guide5').split("~")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="guide in guides">{{guide}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
//controller part
$scope.test = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

// html part
 <div>
   <ul>
   <li  ng-repeat="value in test">{{value}}</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TMkMxebYECVH8gGIraGT?p=preview